# Too much solid debris after filter media change

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, cleaning, filters

I have my tank for about 10 years now. Three years ago filter stopped working and has been replaced with Tetra that was available at hand. It was working fine until couple months ago. It is still working. Only problem I have is that everytime I change filter media and plugin the filter, it is spewing insane amount of solid debris. When it happened first time I lost one of my beloved blood red parrot. Melafix cleaned the infection, but large amounts of solid debris at every filter media change worries me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: solid debris, I am sorry, I do not understand it full (not native speaker...). Which kind is it? parts of the filter filling, or plastic parts, or little rocks? Is it coming out of the filter, or are them items usual laying on the ground and will be moved by the filter?

Comment: Thank you for the response. It looks more like hard water sediment. White in color and some large pieces of what looks like pieces broke off of bacteria colony brown in color.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I have another question ^^ what media do you change? activated charcoal? In my filter this is the only media I change. Do you clean the whole filter with water, when you change the media? (I do this to get rid of sediment and mud)

Comment: filter with activated charcoal. I think filter housing is holding hack of a lot of sediment from hard water and during filter media changes gets disturbed and comes out. I do not clean the while filter housing so that I don't destroy bacteria colonies. I will give it a try next water change and see if problem corrects.

Comment: I clean the housing with a lots of water. I have some small tube-like substrate and a sponge-like mat with makro-pores. There the bacteria live in and even when I rinse it with a lots of water the bacteria will live on. In every cleaning-turn I clean all material and rooms in the filter/pump. I have a turtle in the tank, so I need more cleaning than with fish-only :)